# How to not crash when receiving an unexpected output?

Tags: python, string, input, integer, crash

I am learning python, and foe that I create small programs, and one error I constantly find is not being able to limit the answers to inputs as numbers. When answering a number inside my requirements it works fine, but when nothing or anything besides just numbers is the output for an input it crashes, when I intended it to ask again.

```
#EXAMPLE

def ask(x):

    return int(float(input(x)))

def main():

    x = ask("NUMBER FROM 0 TO 5: ")

    while x > 5 or x < 0 :

        x = ask("PLEASE INPUT A NUMBER FROM 0 TO 5")

    print(x)

main()
```

#If the output to the x input is a number between 0 and 5 it works fine, if if a number outside of this limit it works fine and asks again, but when the output is nothing or an str it crashes down, how can I make it work and ask again?

Answer (score 0):

You can use error handling with this keyword `try` and `except`.

```
def ask(x):
  return int(float(input(x)))

def main():
  while 1:
    try:
      x = ask("NUMBER FROM 0 TO 5: ")
      while x > 5 or x < 0 :
        x = ask("PLEASE INPUT A NUMBER FROM 0 TO 5")
      break
    except:
      print("Please input valid input such as integer or float!")

  print(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Note that, `while 1:` loop will end by `break` keyword if code in `try` block worked without error which hit `break` line. If any error happened, then `catch` block will be executed which print warning message to user to input valid input.